# How to replace long formula with Process Builder or Workflow?

Tags: trigger, process-builder, formula-field

I am getting this error:

> Formula(s) that reference this field are no longer valid: Compiled
>   formula is too big to execute (5,329 characters). Maximum size is
>   5,000 characters (Related field: Formula)

On this formula:

```
IF(
  AND(Start_Date__c >= DPA__r.Contract_Start_Date__c,
      End_Date__c <= DPA__r.Contract_End_Date__c,
      Start_Date__c < End_Date__c),  

  FLOOR(
    (
      (End_Date__c - Start_Date__c) / 
      IF(Number_of_Payments__c == 26, 26, 30)
     ) * 2
   ) / 2
,

IF(
  AND(Start_Date__c < DPA__r.Contract_Start_Date__c,
      End_Date__c <= DPA__r.Contract_End_Date__c,
      DPA__r.Contract_Start_Date__c < End_Date__c),

  FLOOR(
         (
           (End_Date__c - DPA__r.Contract_Start_Date__c) / 
           IF(Number_of_Payments__c == 26, 26, 30)
          ) *2 ) /2, 

   IF(
      AND(
        Start_Date__c >= DPA__r.Contract_Start_Date__c,  
        End_Date__c > DPA__r.Contract_End_Date__c, 
        Start_Date__c < DPA__r.Contract_End_Date__c), 

       FLOOR(((DPA__r.Contract_End_Date__c - Start_Date__c)/30)*2)/2, 

         IF(
           AND(
            Start_Date__c < DPA__r.Contract_Start_Date__c,
            End_Date__c > DPA__r.Contract_End_Date__c, 
            DPA__r.Contract_Start_Date__c < DPA__r.Contract_End_Date__c ),  

         FLOOR(
           (
             (DPA__r.Contract_End_Date__c - DPA__r.Contract_Start_Date__c) 
             /30)*2)/2,

   0
          ) 
    ) 
)
```

)

I looked into solving this with Process Builder. There are two custom objects: DPA__c, and DPA_Pay_Line__c with 'one to many' relationships. DPA_Pay_Line__c has access to DPA__c fields. The field formula above is in DPA_Pay_Line__c object. I need to trigger this field change when DPA__c is edited or when DPA_Pay_Line__c is edited. I build invokable process on DPA_Pay_Line__c to change the value in the required field. But I do not see how I can build another process on DPA__c to trigger the invokable process.

There are similar reasons which prevent to use workflow rules. I cannot access DPA_Pay_Line__c fields to implement the same logic as it is in the formula field.

Is my only option to build triggers on DPA__c and on DPA_Pay_Line__c?

**DPA Pay Line invocable process**

[image]

**process started by new or edited DPA **

[image]

Comment: By definition, if you need to recalculate values on DPA_Line_c whenever DPA__c or DPA_Line__c then you will need to recognize the state change in two PBs or two triggers.  PBs can call invocable method and pass ID of DPA__c and DPA_line__c; PBs can also pass same values to Visual Flow that can do the calc as well if you want to avoid apex

Comment: So, I created an invocable process which changes a field on DPA Pay Line. Next, I have created a process which starts every time a DPA record is updated or edited. I selected to start the invocable process as an action. DPA does not have fields referencing DPA Pay Line. DPA Pay Line has a lookup field to DPA. So, how do I pass DPA Id, or related DPA Pay Line references in Process Variables for DPA process? I have updated the question to include process images.

Comment: Congratulations on getting this formula to actually calculate. That is quite the formula. It is actually only slightly to big, and i think that if you optimize it a little then it might save. However, that would make future additions to this formula difficult, if not impossible. Would that be a concern?

Comment: Only a PB whose object = DPA_Line will have access to the DPA_Line_ID